# Temporarely open a file to use its content as input: with-statement or redirect sys.stdin?

Tags: python, stdout, stdin, with-statement, sys

Let's say for instance I would want to write a function that gets some basic input from a `.txt` file, say some numbers, and I want to print on another `.txt` file those numbers multiplied by 2.

I was taught I can import `sys` and redirect `sys.stdin` and `sys.stdout` to those files, as such

```
import sys

def multiply(filein, fileout):
    global stdin
    global stdout
    origin=sys.stdin #saving the original stdin and stdout
    origout=sys.stdout
    sys.stdin=open(filein,'r')
    sys.stdout=open(fileout,'w')
    for line in sys.stdin:
        nlist = [float(num) for num in line.split()] #the line is now split and each number is converted to float
        for num in nlist:
            sys.stdout.write((f'{num*2} ')) #each number gets multiplied by 2 and converted back to string
        sys.stdout.write('\n') #just to keep each line divided
        
    sys.stdin.close()
    sys.stdout.close()
    sys.stdin=origin
    sys.stdout=origout
```

Everything works just fine, but then I realized I'm importing a library, redirecting the standard input and standard output to the right files, just to redirect them right away back to what they were originally.

That's when the `with` statement came to my mind. Here's the exact same function but I'm using `with` instead of the whole  `stdin` and `stdout` redirection idea.

```
def multiply(filein, fileout):
   with open(filein,'r') as fin, open(fileout,'w') as fout:
       for line in fin:
           nlist = [float(num) for num in line.split()] 
           for num in nlist:
               fout.write((f'{num*2} '))
           fout.write('\n')
```

Which to my eyes looks a lot less clunky.

I was wondering what are the main reasons (if there is any) why I should prefer the first version over the second. Thank you.

Comment: First version can be used to pipe information into an external script (possible limitations). Second version is completely pythonic. Second (simpler) is better in your demo. First version is more all-purpose (extended functionality).

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering what are the main reasons (if there is any) why I should prefer the first version over the second.

I can't think of any.

The `with` context manager is there precisely to get rid of all the boiler plate code from your first example. PLUS, it releases the resource if there's an error, which is something the first example doesn't have.